# Корректность сочетания "святой Иисус Христос"

Tags: семантика

Иисус Христос является святым? Святым может быть только человек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Является, но такое сочетание не используется. Используется "Святой Бог":
https://holychords.com/5376

Словарное значение:
Обладающий высшим совершенством и сверхъестественной силой.
*Святой Дух (одна из трёх ипостасей Бога).

Святое семейство (дева Мария, её муж Иосиф и младенец Христос).

Святая Троица (Бог Отец, Бог Сын и Святой Дух).*

Comment: *Святой Бог* не используется вовсе.

Comment: Используется иногда, даже в Библии есть: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3

Comment: А это у Кузнецова с маленькой.

Comment: Ну один пример только.

Comment: Даже молитва есть такая: *Святый Боже, Святый Крепкий, Святый Безсмертный, помилуй нас.*

Comment: Ну да, согласен, но тут звательный падеж, а не в 3-м лице упоминание.

Comment: Падеж роли не играет, он святость не отменяет.

Answer (score 0):

> Иисус Христос является святым?

нет

> Святым может быть только человек?

да

Comment: А как же Святая Троица?

Comment: *А как же Святая Троица?* Да нормально.)